# Quarkus does not use JaxRs @Path when declared in interface in an external jar

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus

I have a Java interface which declares all things related to JaxRs like this:

```
@Path("/notes-service")
public interface NotesApi {

  @POST
  @Path("/notes")
  @Consumes({ "application/json" })
  @Produces({ "application/json" })
  Response createNote(
    @HeaderParam("Accept-Language") @DefaultValue("en") String acceptLanguage,
    @Valid CreateNoteDTO createNoteDTO);

}
```

The interface is shipped as an external dependency as a jar.

And an implementation in my service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
public class NotesService implements NotesApi {

  @Override
  public Response createNote(String range, CreateNoteDTO createNoteDTO) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Such a setup like above doesn't work. It returnes 404 for an endpoint `/notes-service/notes`

However when I copy the `@Path` part into the implenentation, everything works just fine:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
@Path("/notes-service")
public class NotesService implements NotesApi {

  @Override
  public Response createNote(String range, CreateNoteDTO createNoteDTO) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also another workaaround: When I copy-paste the interface into my service then it also works without `@Path` declaration in an implementation.

This means that `@Path` annotation on interface level works just fine (I have checked it with a minimal service). But it doesn't work when the interface comes as a dependency.

Is it a bug in Quarkus or an expected behavior?

Comment: This might be a bug. Can you open an issue on Github please so we can look into it further?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha It works (I've checked it) but the interface has to lay in the same project as implementation. When I move it outside to a jar - it cannot recognize it.

Comment: @geoand I've done some investigations with a minimal single-module project and it works just fine. But when an interface is packed in an esternal jar it doesn't work. Is it expected?

Comment: I've updated the question explaining the scenario. I will try to share the full multimodule project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an empty beans.xml in your external project in `src/main/resources/META-INF`, so that Quarkus scans your external jar file.

Quarkus documentation also lists other ways to make beans discoverable:

- dependencies that contain a `beans.xml` descriptor (content is ignored)
- dependencies that contain a Jandex index - `META-INF/jandex.idx`
- dependencies referenced by `quarkus.index-dependency` in `application.properties`
- Quarkus integration code.

https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this was the problem

Comment: Not quite the solution (in my case, at least). In my case the REST interface is generated by openapi tools, with error "Unable to find matching target resource method" thrown by similar paths. The issue is discussed [here without resolve by Quarkus engineers](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19299). My (painful) solution was to uniquify clashing paths one by one.