Apache camel quarkus call a route present inside a jar
I have created a apache camel route with quarkus and added this application(App A) to maven repository.In another quarkus apache camel application(App B) I have added the dependency of the App A and try to call the apache camel route present in App A. I get  No consumers available on endpoint exception.
App A sample code:
public void configure() {
from("direct:startappa")
.log("app a started");
}

App B sample code:
public void configure() {
from("direct:startappb")
.log("app b started")
.to("direct:startappa");
}


check the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75004765/quarkus-does-not-use-jaxrs-path-when-declared-in-interface-in-an-external-jar/75046455#75046455

@Serkan adding empty bean.xml like you mentioned worked. Thanks so much.
