How to setup Quarkus for devcontainers, quarkus:dev and micro services?
I have a maven multi-module project that uses Quarkus. Something like:
<project>
  <modules>
     <module>web</module>
     <module>customer</module>
     <module>warehouse</module>
     <module>payment</module>
  </modules>
</project>

Loosely following the answer found here and the Quarkus multi-module guide
The project relies on a RDBMS and a cache. So I setup a devcontainer using docker-compose.yml Each of the modules is an independent micro service with a http interface.
when running quarkus dev (or mvn compile quarkus:dev) on a module it starts in development mode. Now web calls out to the other services, so I add their compiled versions to docker-compose.yml and I can code in the web module.
For developing the customer module, I create a different docker-compose.yml file that loads the compiled web module and the customer module from source, etc. So I end up with one compose file for each module.
This leads to a sub-par development experience: to edit one of the micro services I have to terminate the devcontainer and restart it with a different configuration. This is slow and requires to deal with database persistence.
My question: is there way to setup a devcontainer environment for a multi-module maven project, so I can use quarkus dev concurrently on more than one sub module, so I don't need to go through the shutdown-reconfigure-resart cycle every time?

Turns out, once you wrap your head around (I had help from Alexey) the moving parts, it is quite possible.
Key points:

the Quarkus magic is provided by quarkus-maven-plugin
Only the applications, but not libraries need it
activation needs to happen in a maven profile, so one can target the specific module
applications need their ports configured for http and debug, so they don't overlap between modules
In VSCode you can use launch.json and tasks.json to automate this.

With this setup there is no more need for editing settings between runs. I have documented the insights in a blog entry accompanied by a sample project
YMMV

In your case, you don’t inject anything from your libraries, but if you would then you must add an empty beans.xml in your library projects, if you want Quarkus to scan those too. See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046455/2979325
